# For Angular2, why do two pages (two tabs) having the same component affect each other?

Tags: angular, browser-sync, lite-server

This is an Angular2 app, and the component is simplified here as:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
        <input [(ngModel)]="wahla">
        <input [(ngModel)]="wahla">
        {{ wahla }}
        `
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    wahla = "hmm hmm ha ha";
}
```

I think the app works fine in one page with the two-way binding, but if I open up another tab with http://localhost:3000/ and then paste something or type something in the first page's first input box, then the second tab actually gets updated for its first input box, while the 2nd input box and the static text do not update.

For the first tab, everything is updated as expected.

Is this supposed to happen or what might be wrong?  This is running using `npm start` which is running a lite-server with BrowserSync.

Comment: This even happens in case of different browser on another PC in a network too. any avoidance of this strange feature?

Comment: @HydTechie see Gary's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39465216/3010553

Answer (score 10):

That is a functionality of `lite-server` and not a bug or something as it might appear to be one.

To make this happen `lite-server` [uses](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server) a javascript extention [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/).

On `lite-server`'s npm page it is mentioned like this

> lite-server is a simple customized wrapper around BrowserSync to make
>   it easy to serve SPAs.

and `BrowserSync` puts it on their [website](https://www.browsersync.io/) like this

> Time-saving synchronised browser testing

and this clears all the clouds of doubt

> With each web page, device and browser, testing time grows
>   exponentially. From live reloads to URL pushing, **`form replication`** to
>   click mirroring, Browsersync cuts out repetitive manual tasks.

Comment: however, tab one shows all values sync'ed, but tab two shows only input box 1's value changed and input box 2 and the static text inconsistent with the value in input box 1?

Comment: that's probably because , whatever `BroswerSync` is doing is out of the scope of `angular` or more specifically `zone.js`' angular zone. So the changes are made directly in the `DOM` which doesn't trigger a `change detection` in angular, hence inconsistent values.

Comment: are you able to reproduce it too?  Then I consider it somewhat of a bug, either for Angular2 or for BrowserSync, because supposedly, all 3 values should be identical (all bound by 2-way binding)

Comment: yes! , I think it's just not supported yet by BrowserSync, you can report a bug at their [github repo](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync).

Answer (score 5):

You can change the sync settings by visiting http://localhost:3001 . This is the user interface to change the browser-sync settings. Once you load http://localhost:3001, you can navigate to "Sync Options" and change the settings for "Browser-Sync" here.