# Does angular 2.0 store values of variables on server side?

Tags: angular

I cloned official angular 2.0 quick start projectand try to add side-navigation panel. I created simple component wich contains following:

```
export class AppComponent {
    menuVisible: boolean = false;
    toggleVisible() { this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible; }
}
```

And simple template (pug):

```
side-navigation([class.visible]="menuVisible === true") 
    div(*ngIf="!menuVisible", (click)="toggleVisible()", style="cursor: pointer; font-size:1vw") ☰
    ul(*ngIf="menuVisible")
```

But when I've tried to test this component I get weird issue:
Sometimes I click the open dide panel button in Google Chrome (just for example this issue does not depend on any browser), I see that side-navigation bar opens in another browser (Edge). I don't know how to fix it. Is it my problem or some kind of bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That the browsersync feature of your server.

See also

- [For Angular2, why do two pages (two tabs) having the same component affect each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766614/for-angular2-why-do-two-pages-two-tabs-having-the-same-component-affect-each/36768452#36768452)
- [I use gulp . project is on Angular 2. How to delete browser-sync from the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158821/i-use-gulp-project-is-on-angular-2-how-to-delete-browser-sync-from-the-projec)